# multiple "redefiniton" and "conflicting types" errors

Tags: c

I have a problem with client-serwer project in Eclipse (linux). I am getting multiple "redefiniton of ... " and " conflicting types for ‘...’" errors in eclipse. As a beginner I don't really know what to do with this error. Tried some sulutions but nothing helped. Here is my code::

Main file (part):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "funkcje.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
int sockFD, newSocket, portNO, addr_size;
int reuse = 1;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, newAddr;

if (argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Uruchomienie: sudo %s numer portu\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

sockFD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockFD < 0) {
    showError("Blad podczas towrzenia gniazda\n");
}
printf("Gniazdo poprawnie utworzone \n");

memset((void*) &serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
portNO = atoi(argv[1]);
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portNO);
.
.
.
```

Function code (part):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "funkcje.h"


#define MAX_USERID_LEN 256
#define MAX_PASS_LEN 256
#define MAX_LEN 1024
#define MAX_LINES_IN_MS 20

#define USER 0
#define UNAUTH_USER -1

#define RESPONSE_BYTES 512
#define REQUEST_BYTES 512

struct userInfo {
char userId[MAX_USERID_LEN + 1];
char pass[MAX_PASS_LEN + 1];
};

void showError(char *str) {
perror(str);
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
. 
.
.
```

Header file code (part):

```
#ifndef _funkcje_H_
#define _funkcje_H_
#include "funkcje.c"



void showError(char *str);

void wyswietl(char *str);

void loguj(char *str);

void sendMsgToClient(int clientFD, char *str);
```

Errors:

```
../src/funkcje.c:22:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct userInfo’
struct userInfo {
    ^~~~~~~~
In file included from ../src/funkcje.h:3:0,
             from ../src/funkcje.c:8:
 ../src/funkcje.c:22:8: note: originally defined here
 struct userInfo {
    ^~~~~~~~
 src/subdir.mk:21: recipe for target 'src/funkcje.o' failed
 ../src/funkcje.c:27:6: error: redefinition of ‘showError’
 void showError(char *str) {
  ^~~~~~~~~
  In file included from ../src/funkcje.h:3:0,
             from ../src/funkcje.c:8:
  ../src/funkcje.c:27:6: note: previous definition of ‘showError’ was here
 void showError(char *str) {
  ^~~~~~~~~
  ../src/funkcje.c:32:6: error: redefinition of ‘wyswietl’
   .
   . 
   . 
   .
   ./src/funkcje.c: At top level:
   ../src/funkcje.c:77:17: error: conflicting types for ‘getUserInfo’
    struct userInfo getUserInfo(int newSocket) {
             ^~~~~~~~~~~
   In file included from ../src/funkcje.h:3:0,
             from ../src/funkcje.c:8:
   ../src/funkcje.c:77:17: note: previous definition of ‘getUserInfo’ was               
   here
   struct userInfo getUserInfo(int newSocket) {
             ^~~~~~~~~~~
   ../src/funkcje.c: In function ‘getUserInfo’:
```

Comment: Show the error messages. What is multiple defined?

Comment: -1 SO only works well if people asking questions also respond to comments and give feedack whether provided answer(s) solve the problem or not. Otherwise their questions will be completely useless for other people.

Answer (score 2):

Your include guard does not work as you intent because you have a strange circular inclusion of files:

```c
...
#include "funkcje.h"

...
struct userInfo {
char userId[MAX_USERID_LEN + 1];
char pass[MAX_PASS_LEN + 1];
};

void showError(char *str) {
perror(str);
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

This will include all the content of `funkcje.h` into that c file.

Then in that header you include the C file again. Yikes!

```c
#ifndef _funkcje_H_
#define _funkcje_H_
#include "funkcje.c"
...
```

Which again includes

```c
...
#include "funkcje.h"

...
struct userInfo {
char userId[MAX_USERID_LEN + 1];
char pass[MAX_PASS_LEN + 1];
};

void showError(char *str) {
perror(str);
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

This time the header is not included due to include guard.
But all the content of your .c file is present twice in your file.

The result looke like this:

```c
//#include "funkcje.h"
#ifndef _funkcje_H_
#define _funkcje_H_
//#include "funkcje.c"
...
struct userInfo {
char userId[MAX_USERID_LEN + 1];
char pass[MAX_PASS_LEN + 1];
};

void showError(char *str) {
perror(str);
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
...
struct userInfo {
char userId[MAX_USERID_LEN + 1];
char pass[MAX_PASS_LEN + 1];
};

void showError(char *str) {
perror(str);
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

As general rule:

- Never include a C file into another C or header file unless you have a really good rason which I cannot see here.

As a solution just remove inclusion of the .c file inside your header.